# Python increment rows starting from a month on month

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, itertools-groupby

How to obtain the below result

[image]

Current Month is the column which is to be calculated. We need to get the increment every month starting from Jan-18 for every account id.

Every Account First row/ Record will start from JAN-18, and Second Row will be Feb-18 an so on. We need to increment from Jan-18 till last observation is there for that account id

Above shown is for a sample account and the same has to be applied for multiple account id.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? You could post the code you have written, for suggestions/corrections.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve what you are looking for as follows:

```python
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

acct_id = "123456789"
loan_start_date = date(2018, 1, 31)
current_date = date.today()
dates = pd.date_range(loan_start_date,current_date, freq='M').strftime("%b-%y")

df_columns = [acct_id, loan_start_date, dates]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["current_month"] = dates
df["acct_id"] = acct_id
df["loan_start_date"] = loan_start_date
df = df[["acct_id", "loan_start_date", "current_month"]]

print(df.head())
```

Comment: How to apply the same logic for multiple acct_id as this is working for single account id what for multiple account id present in a dataframe